# SonarQube Scanner Error while running the sonar qube from Jenkins build pipeline

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Part of the Jenkins build pipeline we were running the sonar qube code scan and was working fine, only few days ago it started throwing error as mentioned below

```
Sonar Qube version: 6.7.6 (build 38781)
Sonar Scanner version: sonar-scanner-3.3.0.1492-windows
(Env variable) SONAR_SCANNER : C:\sonar-scanner-3.3.0.1492-windows

00:44:26.810 ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
00:44:26.810 ERROR: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.ScannerPluginInstaller
00:44:26.810 ERROR: Caused by: Unable to load component class org.sonar.home.cache.FileCache
00:44:26.810 ERROR: Caused by: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalConfiguration
00:44:26.810 ERROR: Caused by: Not authorized. Please check the properties sonar.login and sonar.password.
```

We cannot upgrade to newer version , I would like to understand what is causing the issue for Sonar to fail. Appreciate your responses.

Comment: "Caused by: Not authorized" sounds a lot like you have been authenticated but don't have access to the feature/project you are trying to access on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Admin page (Sonarqube) give access to use to run execute sonar analysis and then 
generate login token from UI .
**_ **use propertyb in sonar.properties file** _**

sonar.login=token

Comment: @user2716600 Can you tick on upper arrow of answer so that it will help other as well.